# Evaluating $\int x f(x)\ \mathrm{d}f(x)$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, stieltjes-integral

$$
\int xf(x)\ \mathrm{d}f(x)
$$ I firstly thought we can assume $x$ as a constant but it isn't $f(x)$ depends on $x$ therefore $x$ depends on $f(x)$ . I just couldn't find a way out. If we say $f(x)=x^2$ what would be the result?

Comment: What are the conditions on $f$? The integration should be on an interval. Are you familiar with Riemann-Stieltjes integrals?

Answer (score 1):

This is a [Riemann-Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral). If we assume that $f$ is continuously differentiable, we have that
$$\int f(x) x \mathrm{d}f(x)=\int f(x) x f'(x) \mathrm{d}x$$

Answer (score 0):

Use that

$$x^2 = \int_0^x 2y dy \Rightarrow df(x) = d(x^2) = 2xdx$$

If you don’t understand this, then you might read on lebesgue stieltjes integral.

Answer (score 0):

If we say $f(x)=x^2$ we will have to evaluate the following integral:
$$\int x\cdot x^2 \mathrm {d}(x^2)$$
This can be simplified as below:
$$= \int x^3 \mathrm{d}(x^2)$$
$$= \int x^3\cdot 2x \mathrm{d}x$$
$$= 2\int x^4 \mathrm{d}x$$
$$= \frac25 \cdot x^5 + \mathrm {C}$$
Where $\mathrm{C}$ is the constant of integration